# Redux, react native: equality function not eliminating uneccessary re-renders

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Using redux I have a messages store like so:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const messagesSlice = createSlice({
    name: "messages",
    initialState: {
        messagesData: {}
    },
    reducers: {
        setChatMessages: (state, action) => {
            const existingMessages = state.messagesData
            const {chatId, messagesData} = action.payload

            existingMessages[chatId] = messagesData

            state.messagesData = existingMessages
        }
    }
});
export const setChatMessages = messagesSlice.actions.setChatMessages;
export default messagesSlice.reducer;
```

I use dispatch to set the state in a function like follows:

```
dispatch(setChatMessages({chatId, messagesData}))
```

I access this piece of state like follows. I essentially create an array, and then loop over the keys stored as part of **chatMessages**, and store the corresponding values in an array and attempt to return this array.

```
  const chatMessages = useSelector(state => {
    if (!chatId) return []
    const chatMessagesData = state.messages.messagesData[chatId]
    if (!chatMessagesData) return []

    const messageList = []

    for (const key in chatMessagesData) {
      const message = chatMessagesData[key]
      messageList.push({
        key,
        ...message
      })
      return messageList
    }
  }, {equalityFn: shallowEqual})
```

When initially running this code, I got the error:

```
WARN  Selector unknown returned a different result when called with the same parameters. This can lead to unnecessary rerenders.
Selectors that return a new reference (such as an object or an array) should be memoized:
```

I added the **shallowEqual** equality function to attempt to deal with this issue, and it worked in other cases in my app, however failed to solve the issue in this case. Any solutions to fix this issue? Thanks.

EDIT:

```
export const getAllChatMessages = (state) => state.messages.messagesData

export const selectSpecificChatMessages = createSelector([getAllChatMessages, (state, chatId) => chatId], (messages, chatId) => {
        if (!chatId) return []
    const chatMessagesData = messages[chatId]
    if (!chatMessagesData) return []

    const messageList = []

    for (const key in chatMessagesData) {
      const message = chatMessagesData[key]
      messageList.push({
        key,
        ...message
      })
      return messageList
    }
})
```

Use of new selector:

```
  const chatMessages = useSelector(state => selectSpecificChatMessages(state, chatId))
```

EDIT 2:
This shows how the dispatch occurs:

```
 dispatch(setChatMessages({chatId, messagesData}))
```

This shows how the reducer is setup:

```
const messagesSlice = createSlice({
    name: "messages",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setChatMessages: (state, action) => {
            const existingMessages = state.messagesData
            const {chatId, messagesData} = action.payload

            existingMessages[chatId] = messagesData

            state.messagesData = existingMessages
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your arrays are *not* shallow equal to each other.

It's okay to return a new array reference here in `useSelector`, ***if* you're using `shallowEqual` instead of the default reference comparison**.

*However*... you are putting *copies* of objects into that array.  That means that the old and new arrays *are not* shallow equal.  Shallow equality means that `firstArray[i] === secondArray[i]`, for every index, and that won't be the case here.

Comment: Hi, how would I go about solving this issue. As when I remove **shallowEqual**, the same error appears. Would I add a different equality function? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that your selector's results are _neither_ reference-equal nor shallow-equal.  They might be _deep_-equal... but at that point you should really be writing _memoized_ selectors that only recalculate the results when necessary: https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors#writing-memoized-selectors-with-reselect

Comment: Please check the edit I added to the post. Esentially thr warning has gone away, however the selector now wont select the new messages that are sent, i.e when **setChatMessages** is called again. What would I have to make the selector update and select the latest Chat messages when dispatches occurs?

Comment: The selector _should_ re-run any time `state.messages.messagesData` changes. I'd suggest double-checking your reducer and how you're doing the updates.

Comment: I have provided another update. I am unsure what to do to the reducer so that it reacts to **state.messages.messagesData** changes. How would I implement the reducer in the correct way? Thanks.

Comment: @EesaMunir It shouldn't make a difference, but have you tried mutating `state.messagesData[chatId]` directly? The intermediate var seems to be there only for clarity/readability? Another thing, this dance you're doing in the selector with `key in chatMessagesData` is basically (almost) what `Object.entries()` does, maybe consider simplifying the selector and letting the components transform the data as they need it.